# Is it possible to mute users in a certain voice channel, not removing them from the channel in discord? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to mute a user in a certain voice channel without creating a role "Muted" for it.
Here is my code:

```
await voiceChat.set_permissions(target=user, speak=False)
```

But it works only when the user is rejoining the channel. Is there a way to make it work live?

Comment: You don't want to set the permission. You want to edit the member to mute/unmute: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20utils#discord.Member.edit To use that command you need the relevant permissions. This will be a server mute which they cannot undo. So please write a robust logic that unmutes the member as well

Comment: Thank you, got it now! Now it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20utils#discord.Member.edit
You can use .edit(mute = True) to mute a user you need.