# Discord bot to mute the voice of people Using Voice Chat with the help of Python

Tags: python, discord

I am trying to make a Discord bot that mutes the voice of the participant using voice chat.

For this, I am using Python.

This is my code, but it is not working as expected.

```py
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands 

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=" !") 

@client.event 
async def on_ready():
     print('BOT ACTIVATED')

@client.command() 
async def mute(ctx):
     voice_client = ctx.guild.voice_client
     if not voice_client:
         return
     channel = voice_client.channel
     await voice_client.voice_state(ctx.guild.id, channel.id, self_mute=True)
 
client.run(My Token)
```

The idea I have is:

Command I will enter: `!muteall` \

And the bot will mute all the participants in the voice chat

Command I will enter: `!unmuteall` \

And the bot will unmute all the participants in the voice chat.

Comment: Can you show your entire code file, minus the token? Do you have the `@client.command()` decorator above `async def mute` ? What is `main_ws` supposed to be in `voice_client.main_ws.voice_state()` ? I can't find it in the discord.py docs

Comment: `import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=" !")
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('BOT ACTIVATED')

@client.command()
async def mute(ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.guild.voice_client
    if not voice_client:
        return
    channel = voice_client.channel
    await voice_client.voice_state(ctx.guild.id, channel.id, self_mute=True)

client.run(My Token)`

Answer (score 1):

Before we get to the crux of the question, a short word on your prefix:
Your command prefix is  `!` with a space beforehand. I do not know if this was intentional or not, but if it was, in my testing I found using this to be impossible. Discord strips beginning whitespace so all my messages  `!test` come out as `!test`.

After fixing this, attempting to use the `!mute` command produces an error:
`'VoiceClient' object has no attribute 'voice_state'`
Indeed, I have been unable to find anything like this in the docs. It took me a lot of searching, but I may have [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62282630/is-it-possible-to-mute-users-in-a-certain-voice-channel-not-removing-them-from) what you wanted.

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!") 

@client.command() 
async def mute(ctx):
        voice_client = ctx.guild.voice_client #get bot's current voice connection in this guild
        if not voice_client:  #if no connection...
            return  #probably should add some kind of message for the users to know why nothing is happening here, like ctx.send("I'm not in any voice channel...")
        channel = voice_client.channel #get the voice channel of the voice connection
        people = channel.members #get the members in the channel
        for person in people: #loop over those members
            if person == client.user: #if the person being checked is the bot...
                continue #skip this iteration, to avoid muting the bot
            await person.edit(mute=True, reason="{} told me to mute everyone in this channel".format(ctx.author))
            #edit the person to be muted, with a reason that shows in the audit log who invoked this command. Line is awaited because it involves sending commands ("mute this user") to the server then waiting for a response.
```

Your bot will need permissions to mute users.