# Discord Bot To Mute The Voice Of People Using Voice Chat using Python

Tags: python, discord

I am 15 and I am trying to make a discord bot that mutes the voice of the participant using voice chat. For this, I am using Python. This is my code but it is not working as expected.

```
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=" !")
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('BOT ACTIVATED')

@client.command()
async def mute(ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.guild.voice_client
    if not voice_client:
        return
    channel = voice_client.channel
    await voice_client.main_ws.voice_state(ctx.guild.id, channel.id, self_mute=True)

client.run('')
```

The idea I have is:
Command I Will Enter: !muteall
and the bot will mute all the participants in the voice chat
Command I Will Enter: !unmuteall
and the bot will unmute all the participants in the voice chat

Pls someone help me in this!!!!!!

Comment: I've written an answer on your prior question: [Discord Bot To Mute The Voice Of People Using Voice Chat with the help of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64039832/discord-bot-to-mute-the-voice-of-people-using-voice-chat-with-the-help-of-python)